# Change the order status from the order list by adding a drop-down menu

Tags: woocommerce

I have this code to add into the order listing a button to change the order status from the order list instead of going into the order details :

```
/**
 * Ajouter une nouvelle colonne "Modifier le statut" à la liste des commandes
 */
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'ajouter_colonne_modifier_statut_commande' );
function ajouter_colonne_modifier_statut_commande( $columns ) {
    $columns['modifier_statut'] = __( 'Modifier le statut', 'woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
}

/**
 * Afficher le menu déroulant de modification du statut de commande dans la colonne "Modifier le statut"
 */
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'afficher_menu_deroulant_statut_commande', 2 );
function afficher_menu_deroulant_statut_commande( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $column == 'modifier_statut' ) {
        // Vérifie si l'utilisateur a la capacité de modifier le statut de la commande
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Récupérer les transitions de statut de commande disponibles pour cette commande
        $transitions = wc_get_order_statuses();
        unset( $transitions['wc-cancelled'] ); // Supprimer la transition d'annulation

        // Si aucune transition n'est disponible, afficher un message d'erreur
        if ( empty( $transitions ) ) {
            echo '<span style="color:red">' . __( 'Aucune transition de statut disponible pour cette commande', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
            return;
        }

        // Afficher le menu déroulant de modification du statut de commande
        $current_status = $post->post_status;
        $nonce_url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' );
        ?>
        <form class="woocommerce-inline-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( $nonce_url ); ?>" method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ); ?>
            <select name="order_status">
                <?php foreach ( $transitions as $transition => $status ) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $transition ); ?>" <?php selected( $current_status, $transition ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $status ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="save" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Modifier', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}
```

the code works, but it still remaining the link on the order line which link to the order details. It means when you click to unroll the menu you are directed directly to the order details.
Someone could help me with this ?

UPDATE :
Now the link has desappeared, it was able to test the code, and unfortunately doesn't work properly. I have an issue with the modification of the status itself, the roll-down menu works, the confirmation button too, the code seems to be executed, but the status is not updated.
Here is the complete code :

```
// Ajouter une nouvelle colonne "Modifier le statut" à la liste des commandes
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'ajouter_colonne_modifier_statut_commande' );
function ajouter_colonne_modifier_statut_commande( $columns ) {
    $columns['modifier_statut'] = __( 'Modifier le statut', 'woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
}

// Afficher le menu déroulant de modification du statut de commande dans la colonne "Modifier le statut"
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'afficher_menu_deroulant_statut_commande', 2 );
function afficher_menu_deroulant_statut_commande( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( $column == 'modifier_statut' ) {
        // Vérifie si l'utilisateur a la capacité de modifier le statut de la commande
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Récupérer les transitions de statut de commande disponibles pour cette commande
        $transitions = wc_get_order_statuses();
        unset( $transitions['wc-cancelled'] ); // Supprimer la transition d'annulation

        // Si aucune transition n'est disponible, afficher un message d'erreur
        if ( empty( $transitions ) ) {
            echo '<span style="color:red">' . __( 'Aucune transition de statut disponible pour cette commande', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
            return;
        }

        // Afficher le menu déroulant de modification du statut de commande
        $current_status = $post->post_status;
        $nonce_url = wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&order_id=' . $post->ID ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' );
        ?>
        <form class="woocommerce-inline-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( $nonce_url ); ?>" method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ); ?>
            <select name="order_status">
                <?php foreach ( $transitions as $transition => $status ) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $transition ); ?>" <?php selected( $current_status, $transition ); ?>><?php echo esc_html( $status ); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="save" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Modifier', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        </form>
        <?php
    }
}

// Enregistrer le nouveau statut de la commande lorsqu'on soumet le formulaire de modification de statut
add_action( 'woocommerce_saved_order_items', 'enregistrer_statut_commande', 10, 2 );
function enregistrer_statut_commande( $order_id, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['order_status'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['order_status'] ) ) {
        $new_status = sanitize_key( $_POST['order_status'] );
        wc_mark_order_status( $order_id, $new_status, 'Changement de statut de commande manuel', true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to disable the Orders page table row link:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'bbloomer_disable_admin_orders_table_row_link' );

function bbloomer_disable_admin_orders_table_row_link( $classes ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $current_screen = get_current_screen();
        if ( $current_screen->base == 'edit' && $current_screen->post_type == 'shop_order' ) $classes[] = 'no-link';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```